# Differing html from layout order in article

Tags: html, css

Look at this HTML and CSS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Floats</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .left {
            float:left;
            width:100px;
        }
        .right {
            float:right;
            width:400px;
        }
        body {
            width:500px;
        }
        div {
            outline:solid red 1px;
            padding-bottom: 20px;
        }
        .blue {
            outline-color:blue
        }
        .green {
            outline-color:green;
            height:20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="left green"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="left blue"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The green box is the image of variable height
The red boxes are blocks that the article is made up of
The blue box is related information

I want to know how to get the blue box to appear directly after the green box without the space in between that is caused by the red boxes, but still keep the blue box at the very end in the HTML?

Comment: I think my solution allows you have the green box height variable. Check it out

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to move an element that's on the top to the bottom in Responsive design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115995/what-is-the-best-way-to-move-an-element-thats-on-the-top-to-the-bottom-in-respo)

Answer (score 1):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/ztUt4/8/

```
<div class="left green">
</div>
<div class="rights">

<div class="right">
</div>

<div class="right">
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
    </div>
<div class="left blue">
</div>
```

Comment: The Op does not want any change in the HTML. He wants the blue box html at the end

Comment: @AnaMaria yes, I want to keep the blue box at the very end

Comment: There is still an issue. The OP said the height of the green box is variable. So if i increase the height of the green box it overlaps the blue box.

Answer (score 1):

```
ok. try this. I modified your code little bit.
**Here is your HTML -** 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class='container'>
    <div class='leftNav'>
       <div class="green"></div>
      <div class="blue"></div>
    </div>

     <div class='rightNav'>
       <div class="right"></div>
       <div class="right"></div>
       <div class="right"></div>
       <div class="right"></div>
       <div class="right"></div>
       <div class="right"></div>
     </div>

  </div><!-- main container closing tag  -->
</div>
</body>
</html>

**Here is your css -**
.container {
  width: 450px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  position: relative;
}
.leftNav {
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
.rightNav {
  width: 320px;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
}
.green {
  border: solid thin green;
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 135px;
  background: green;
}
.blue {
  border: solid thin blue;
  width: 120px;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 75px;
  background: blue;
}
.right {
  width: 320px;
  height: 45px;
  background: gray;
  margin:3px 0;
}
```

Here is the demo link:
http://jsbin.com/uhazad/1

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution too. I enclosed all the 4 rights div in one main div.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EZd6q/)

HTML

```
<div class="left green"></div>
<div class="rights">
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
<div class="left blue"></div>
```

CSS

```
.left {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
.rights {
    float:right;
    width:400px;
    margin-top:0px
}
body {
    width:500px;
}
div {
    outline:solid red 1px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.blue {
    outline-color:blue;
    height:10px;
}
.green {
    outline-color:green;
    height:30px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the Edit and +1. Does the answer serve your purpose?

Comment: So far it is the best answer (along with similar answers below), although it does not allow me to add a random box in between the "right" boxes that would appear under the green box

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute for blue divider for keep it very end of it's parent:

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gFwZt/)

CSS:

```
body {
    width:500px;
}
.main {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.left {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
}
.right {
    float:right;
    width:400px;
}
.red {
    border:solid red 1px;
}
.green {
    border:solid green 1px;
    height:20px;
}
.blue {
    border:solid blue 1px;    
    position: absolute;
    width:inherit;
    height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="green">green</div>
        <div class="blue">blue</div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="red">1</div>  
        <div class="red">2</div>
        <div class="red">3</div>
        <div class="red">4</div>
        <div class="red">5</div>
        <div class="red">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```