# How to make text wrapable around following, floated element?

Tags: html, css, floating

HTML:

```
<div class="heading">
  <h2 class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
  <a class="action" href="#">Print</a>
</div>
```

Desired default look:

```
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit      [Print] |
| amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. |
```

Desired look on small screen (using media-queries):

```
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit |
| amet, consectetur     |
| adipiscing elit.      |
| [Print]               |
```

Not desired:

```
|                            [Print] |
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,        |
| consectetur adipiscing elit.       |
```

Not desired:

```
| Lorem ipsum dolor sit      [Print] |
| amet, consectetur                  |
| adipiscing elit.                   |
```

Remarks:

- Text may be any long.
- Action element is constant height and variable width.

I see no way to do this using only CSS.

Right now I use JS ([Harvey](http://harvesthq.github.io/harvey/) lib) to put floated DOM element before text on bigger screen.

Any ideas?

**/// EDIT - moved to answer** (sorry for mess)

Comment: Sorry for wrong tags order. I can't change it now.

Comment: Wrong tags order? HTML tags or stack overflow tags?

Comment: The floated element either needs to be first in the markup or within the h2.  http://cssdeck.com/labs/mxwjhbbs

Comment: The problem here is that to achieve the first desired effect the anchor tag must be **before** the headline. And to achieve the second desired effect the anchor must be **after** the headline.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to move an element that's on the top to the bottom in Responsive design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115995/what-is-the-best-way-to-move-an-element-thats-on-the-top-to-the-bottom-in-respo)

Comment: @StevenV, stack overflow tags. It's CSS problem and I didn't know that first will be used in question title.

Comment: @lama Tags are displayed with the most popular first. You can't set the order they are displayed, even if you add them to the question in another order.

Comment: @cimmanon, the question that you mention is similar but definitely not the same and may have different solution. Especially Felxbox don't go with text wrapping. And of course I know that floated needs to be before h2, but then semantics fail. Or maybe it's not so important?

Comment: You must decide which is more important: semantics or desired appearance.  The effect you're looking for with dynamically sized elements is impossible with pure CSS while retaining pure/semantic markup.  Your 2nd "not desired" example is the best compromise between looks/purity.  This is what a Flexbox solution would look like, btw:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/9bntxaro

Comment: @cimmanon, thanks for your suggestion about deciding. I sometimes suffer for being too semantic-puristic, which makes me blind about some solutions. I will make an edit in the moment.

Comment: It's preferred that you submit an answer, rather than modifying the question to contain your solution.

Answer (score 2):

There's no easy way to achieve both results using only CSS without modifying your markup. There are a few tricks you can use to try to emulate the behavior you want, though.

**Trick 1: Use Absolute Positioning**

Set the link to `position:absolute;top:0;right:0;` (and the container to `position:relative;` if needed). Then, use `.text::before{display":block;content' ';float:right;}` to place a gap where the print link will appear.

**Trick 2: Double Links**

You could place a link before/in the `<h2>` to float right for large displays, then hide it and show a (formerly-hidden) second link as a block element below the text on small displays.

Comment: Double links are the best no javascript solution I can think of for this.

Comment: @David, trick 1 would require to know the size of floated element, to size the pseudo-element gap. And trick 2 become problematic when the floating element is something more than single link. I am expected to put there inline forms etc.

Comment: Then it sounds like you'll probably end up needing a JS-based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to suggestions above, I finally decided to break pure semantics structure and put `.action` element before `.text`, so it floats easily with proper text wrapping. Adding the behavior desired for smaller screen was quite easy with the constrains about `.action` element size:

[cssdeck.com/labs/epcoxk7o](http://cssdeck.com/labs/epcoxk7o)

HTML:

```
<div class="heading">
  <a class="action" href="#">Print</a>
  <h2 class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h2>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.action {
  float: right;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 70px;
  background: #eee;
}
.text {
  line-height: 30px;
}

@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .heading {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .action {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

Other solution would be what @cimmanon suggested: [cssdeck.com/labs/9bntxaro](http://cssdeck.com/labs/9bntxaro)