# How to order divs in CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a couple of `div`s and I want to push the first `div` underneath the second on smaller screens, but I've no idea how this can be done.

On viewport `> 1000px`

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

On viewport `< 1000px` I'd like it to be

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="second"></div>
  <div class="first"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.group {
  width: 100%;
}
.first,
.second {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .first,
  .second {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Is there any possibility to achieve such thing?

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tX8LT/)

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle.

Comment: why not just use z-index

Comment: Possible duplicat - [What is the best way to move an element that's on the top to the bottom in Responsive design](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115995/what-is-the-best-way-to-move-an-element-thats-on-the-top-to-the-bottom-in-respo)

Comment: @JamesBlack `z-index`? Can you put one below the other one as described in the question?

Comment: You can do this with absolute positioning. However, you do need to know the size of the elements

Comment: Here you go.. http://jsfiddle.net/yPW76/

Comment: @Mr.Alien That is indeed one way to do it lol Nice. Create an answer, may also want to tell the OP what's going on in there.

Comment: @Ruddy I didn't answered cuz reason 1, I am not sure OP has the elements of fixed height, it's responsive so I am sure it won't be fixed, and secondly, I've hit the rep cap already *(Kidding, I answer for fun and not for rep ;))*

Comment: If you're only targeting modern browsers, have a look at [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) and the [`order` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order)

Answer (score 2):

Right I think this should work for you, take a look and let me know.

### CSS:

```
.group {
    width: 100%;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
    .second {
        float: left;
    }
    .first, .second {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .second {
        float: right;
    }
    .first, .second {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
.first {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.second {
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/tX8LT/3/)

So we just swap the `float` around to swap the `div` to sit the place we want it. Pretty simple huh? :D.

**Note:** Im not `100%` sure if this is how you wanted them to sit or if you wanted the first `div` on the second `div` and not floating by its side.

Answer (score 0):

U can do One thing make a div and copy the content of the div with class first and keep it display none for resolution > 1000 and make it display block below 1000 and keep the  div.first display none.That is the only solution u can do for it .

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery for this

```
var width = $(window).width();
$( window ).resize(function() {
  if(width < 1000){ 
    $(".first").before($(".second"));
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tX8LT/7/