# How can I move one div from top to bottom for mobile screens?

Tags: javascript, css

Is their any way I can move one div from top to bottom for mobile phone screens using media queries or CSS. Please help

Comment: Can you explain the use case a little more? Do you mean when the page is viewed on a computer the div is on the top and if it's viewed on a mobile device it should be on the bottom?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. It will help people looking to answer this question if you could share what you have tried or create a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates the problem you are facing. Check out this [Handy Guide on Asking Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider updating your question:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the best way to move an element that's on the top to the bottom in Responsive design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115995/what-is-the-best-way-to-move-an-element-thats-on-the-top-to-the-bottom-in-respo)

Answer (score 1):

Yes its very easy using media queries so for example

**html**

```
 <div class="top">
     <p>Hello</p>
 </div>
```

**css**

```
 top{
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
 }

 @media (max-width: 768px){
     bottom: 0 !important;
 }
```

something as simple as this will do what you have described but without more information to go on I cant eleborate any further. I would look into media queries as well because this is quite basic stuff, there are lots of great tutorials online.

Comment: If this answer helped you dont forget to mark it as correct!